# How to capture the output of execvp() function in c?

Tags: c

I'm using `execvp()` function in C. 
 My code:

```
pid_t pid = fork();
 if(pid < 0)
            printf("Fork faild\n");
         else if(pid == 0)
         {
            // chirld process
         } 
         else
         {
            // parent process
            execvp(args[0],args) 
         }
```

with `args` variable is `"ls"`. My screen display particular file such as

> a.txt , b.c , c.pdf

....etc.
So.. Can this function return to a variable? 
Such as:

> char str[MAX] = " a.txt b.c c.pdf ";

Sorry my english is bad.

**UPDATE**

I need send result of `execvp()` function from server to client using `send()` , `recv()`.

Comment: yes, you can capture the output of externally executed applications.

Comment: There's `popen` for that. If you insist on doing it manually, you need a `pipe` between the two processes.

Comment: Since `exec*()` does not return (unless there is a failure to start your child process), it cannot return the output of that child. As @PSkocik suggests, look into the `popen()` function, which creates a pipe you can read to get the child's output.

Answer (score 1):

If it is enough to capture stdout, `popen` is a good git. It will create a pipe and will fork the process under the hood, so it is not needed to do it manually.

Simple example of `popen` usage:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        FILE* p = popen("ls -la", "r");
        if (!p) return 1;

        char buff[1024];
        while (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), p)) {
                printf("%s", buff);
        }
        pclose(p);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can I use the result of `execvp("ls -la", &address)` into `FILE* p = popen("ls -la", "r");` ?
Such as `FILE* p = popen("the result of execvp() function", "r");`
Thank.

Comment: I'm implementing socket program. I need result of this to put into stream to send for client program using `recv()`.

I mean. When I type `"ls"` command from server , client will receive result of server execute..

Comment: I need send result of `execvp()` function from server to client using `send()` , `recv()`.

Comment: @LợiNguyễn - you can't use `execvp()` and `popen()` together. `execvp()` doesn't return to caller. It replaces the caller. `popen()` is very similar to `execvp()` in functionality that it executes the commands passed to it and it writes to the FILE stream passed to it.

Comment: @alvits: I'm using `pipe()` and `fork()`. I will put data into `pipefd[1]` from parrent proccess to `pipefd[0]` of children process. Is this ok?

Comment: @LợiNguyễn - you will need to close stdout `close(1)` of the parent process and replace it with `pipefd[1]` using `dup(pipefd[1])` then calling `execvp()`. Note that after the command is executed, your parent is gone because `execvp()` will never come back.

Comment: @alvits [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33516340/how-to-send-result-of-execute-command-from-server-to-client]. 
Help me!