# How to send result of execute command from server to client?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm implementing a socket program in C.

**Program description:**
After server and client have been connected, the client sends a command to the server.
The server receives the request from the client and executes it.
The server sends the result of the execution to the client.
The client will display that server execute and display.

**My problem:** 
**Server:**
I put result of `execvp()` function into pipe `pipefd[1]` and send this data to the client with `send()`.
**Client:**
I receive  `recv()` data to server and display.

But it doesn't work.

**Result that I want:**
***Client*** : `ls`

**Server:**

> a.txt   b.pdf    c.jpg

**Client:**

> a.txt b.pdf c.jpg

**Here is my code:**

**Server:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXPENDING 5
#define BUFFSIZE 32
#define MAX 128
void Die(char *mess) 
{
    perror(mess);
    exit(1);
}
void setup(char inputBuffer[], char *args[], int *background) //Ham xu li (cat) chuoi lenh
{
        const char s[4] = " \t\n";
        char *token;
        token = strtok(inputBuffer, s);
        int i = 0;
        while( token != NULL)
        {
            args[i] = token;
            i++;
            //printf("%s\n", token);
            token = strtok(NULL,s);
        }
        args[i] = NULL;
}
void HandeClient(int sock){

char buffer[BUFFSIZE];
int received = -1;
char data[MAX];

    data[0] = '\0';

    /*recv() from client;*/
    if((received = recv(sock, buffer,BUFFSIZE,0))<0){

        Die("Failed");
    }

    buffer[received] = '\0';

    strcat (data,  buffer);
    while(received>0)
    {
        /* send() from server; //acknowledge to client */
        if(send(sock,buffer, received,0)!= received){
            Die("Failed");
        }
        /* recv() from client; */
        if((received=recv(sock,buffer,BUFFSIZE,0))<0){
            Die("Failed");
        }

        buffer[received] = '\0';
        strcat (data, buffer);
    }

    puts (data);
    {
        char *args[100];
        setup(data,args,0);

        // pipe
        int pipefd[2],lenght;

        pipe(pipefd);

        pid_t pid = fork();
        char path[MAX];

        if(pid>0)
        {
            // parent process // write to pipe

            execvp(args[0],args);
            dup2(1,pipefd[1]);
            close(pipefd[0]);
            write(STDOUT_FILENO,pipefd[1],strlen(pipefd[1]));
            close(pipefd[1]);
            while (wait(NULL) != pid);
        }
        else
            if(pid==0)
            {
                //child process // read from pipe

                close(pipefd[1]);
                while(lenght=read(pipefd[0],path,1) > 0){
                    // send the result of execvp for client.
                    if(send(sock,path,strlen(path),0) != strlen(path) ){
                        Die("Failed");
                    }
                }
                close(pipefd[0]);
                exit(1);//
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Error !\n");
                exit(0);//
            }
    }
    if (strcmp (data, "exits")==0)
    {
        exit (1);
    }
    close(sock);
}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int serversock,clientsock;
    struct sockaddr_in echoserver, echoclient;
    /*if(argc !=2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "USAGE: echoserver <port>\n");
        exit(0);
    }*/
    if((serversock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP))<0){
        Die("Failed");
    }
    memset(&echoserver,0,sizeof(echoserver));
    echoserver.sin_family = AF_INET;
    echoserver.sin_addr.s_addr= htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    echoserver.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));

    if(bind(serversock, (struct sockaddr *) & echoserver,sizeof(echoserver))<0){
        Die("Failed");
    }
    if(listen(serversock,MAXPENDING)<0){
        Die("Failed");
    }
    while(1)
    {
        unsigned int clientlen = sizeof(echoclient);
        if((clientsock = 
            accept(serversock,(struct sockaddr *) &echoclient,
                                &clientlen))<0){
            Die("Failed");
        }
        fprintf(stdout, "Client connected: %s\n",
                        inet_ntoa(echoclient.sin_addr));
        fprintf(stdout,"Message from client:");
        HandeClient(clientsock);        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Client:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#define BUFFSIZE 32
/// Client chuyen mot chuoi ki tu, sau khi an enter n gui cho server roi ket thuc
void Die(char *mess) 
{
    perror(mess); 
    exit(1); 
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
while(1){
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in echoserver;
    char buffer[BUFFSIZE];
    unsigned int echolen;
    int received = 0;
    if (argc != 3) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "USAGE: TCPecho <server_ip> <word> <port>\n");
        exit(1);
    }
/* Create the TCP socket */
    if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0) 
    {
        Die("Failed to create socket");
    }
/* Construct the server sockaddr_in structure */
    memset(&echoserver, 0, sizeof(echoserver));
    echoserver.sin_family = AF_INET;
    echoserver.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
    echoserver.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));
/* Establish connection */
    if (connect(sock,(struct sockaddr *) &echoserver,sizeof(echoserver)) < 0) 
    {
        Die("Failed to connect with server");
    }
/* Send the word to the server */
    //tao mot chuoi s, chuoi s nhan ki tu tu ban phim, roi chuyen cho phia server
    char s[100];
    fgets(s,100,stdin);
    echolen = strlen(s);

    /*  send() from client; */
    if (send(sock, s, echolen, 0) != echolen) 
    {
        Die("Mismatch in number of sent bytes");
    }
/* Receive the word back from the server */
    fprintf(stdout, "Message from server: ");
    while (received < echolen) 
    {
        int bytes = 0;
        /* recv() from server; */
        if ((bytes = recv(sock, buffer, BUFFSIZE-1, 0)) < 1) 
        {
            Die("Failed to receive bytes from server");
        }
        received += bytes;
        buffer[bytes] = '\0';
        /* Assure null terminated string */
        fprintf(stdout, buffer);
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "\n");
    close(sock);
    if(strcmp(s,"exit") == 0)
    exit(0);
}
}
```

Comment: Any statement past `execvp()` will never get executed. As soon as the parent calls `execvp()`, the new process will replace the parent process. All `exec*()` family never returns to the caller. This must be the last call within a process and the process is then considered gone (replaced by the new process). Move the call to `execvp()` before the `while` loop and delete the `while` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified the code to what I believe is your intended behavior. Note that `execvp()` is being executed at the end instead of the beginning as in your original code. I fixed a few places where both server and client were attempting to receive when one of them should be sending.

I added while loop to allow executing commands until client types exit.

Please see the comments within the code.

**Server**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define MAXPENDING 5
#define BUFFSIZE 2048
#define MAX 2048
void Die(char *mess) 
{
    perror(mess);
    exit(1);
}

void setup(char inputBuffer[], char *args[], int *background) //Ham xu li (cat) chuoi lenh
{
    const char s[4] = " \t\n";
    char *token;
    token = strtok(inputBuffer, s);
    int i = 0;
    while( token != NULL)
    {
        args[i] = token;
        i++;
        //printf("%s\n", token);
        token = strtok(NULL,s);
    }
    args[i] = NULL;
}

void HandeClient(int sock){

char buffer[BUFFSIZE];
int received = -1;
char data[MAX];
memset(data,0,MAX);

while(1) { // this will make server wait for another command to run until it receives exit
    data[0] = '\0';
    if((received = recv(sock, buffer,BUFFSIZE,0))<0){

        Die("Failed");
    }

    buffer[received] = '\0';

    strcat (data,  buffer);
    if (strcmp(data, "exit")==0) // this will force the code to exit
        exit(0);
/* This block causes server to wait for more data from client when all data are already received.
    while(received>0)
    {
        if(send(sock,buffer, received,0)!= received){
            Die("Failed");
        }
        if((received=recv(sock,buffer,BUFFSIZE,0))<0){
            Die("Failed");
        }

        buffer[received] = '\0';
        strcat (data, buffer);
    }
*/

    puts (data);
        char *args[100];
        setup(data,args,0);
        int pipefd[2],lenght;

        if(pipe(pipefd))
            Die("Failed to create pipe");

        pid_t pid = fork();
        char path[MAX];

        if(pid==0)
        {
            close(1); // close the original stdout
            dup2(pipefd[1],1); // duplicate pipfd[1] to stdout
            close(pipefd[0]); // close the readonly side of the pipe
            close(pipefd[1]); // close the original write side of the pipe
            execvp(args[0],args); // finally execute the command
        }
        else
            if(pid>0)
            {
                close(pipefd[1]);
                memset(path,0,MAX);
                while(lenght=read(pipefd[0],path,MAX-1)){
                    printf("Data read so far %s\n", path);
                    if(send(sock,path,strlen(path),0) != strlen(path) ){
                        Die("Failed");
                    }
                    fflush(NULL);
                    printf("Data sent so far %s\n", path);
                memset(path,0,MAX);
                }
                close(pipefd[0]);
                //exit(1); removed so server will not terminate
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Error !\n");
                exit(0);//
            }
}
/*
    if (strcmp (data, "exit")==0)
    {
        exit (1);
    }
    printf("Closing socket\n");
    close(sock);
*/
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int serversock,clientsock;
    struct sockaddr_in echoserver, echoclient;
    unsigned int clientlen = sizeof(echoclient);
    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN); // this will allow code to handle SIGPIPE instead of crashing
    if((serversock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP))<0){
        Die("Failed");
    }
    memset(&echoserver,0,sizeof(echoserver));
    echoserver.sin_family = AF_INET;
    echoserver.sin_addr.s_addr= htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    echoserver.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));

    if(bind(serversock, (struct sockaddr *) & echoserver,sizeof(echoserver))<0){
        Die("Failed");
    }
    if(listen(serversock,MAXPENDING)<0){
        Die("Failed");
    }
    while(1)
    {
        if((clientsock = 
            accept(serversock,(struct sockaddr *) &echoclient,
                                &clientlen))<0){
            Die("Failed");
        }
        fprintf(stdout, "Client connected: %s\n",
                        inet_ntoa(echoclient.sin_addr));
        fprintf(stdout,"Message from client:");
        HandeClient(clientsock);        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Client**

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #define BUFFSIZE 2048

    void Die(char *mess) 
    {
        perror(mess); 
        exit(1); 
    }
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
    {
        int sock;
        struct sockaddr_in echoserver;
        char buffer[BUFFSIZE];
        unsigned int echolen;
        int received = 0;
        if (argc != 3) 
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "USAGE: TCPecho <server_ip> <word> <port>\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0) 
        {
            Die("Failed to create socket");
        }
        memset(&echoserver, 0, sizeof(echoserver));
        echoserver.sin_family = AF_INET;
        echoserver.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
        echoserver.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));
        if (connect(sock,(struct sockaddr *) &echoserver,sizeof(echoserver)) < 0) 
        {
            Die("Failed to connect with server");
        }
        char s[100];
    while(1) { // to repeat the whole process until exit is typed
        fgets(s,100,stdin);
        s[strlen(s)-1]='\0'; //fgets doesn't automatically discard '\n'
        echolen = strlen(s);

        /*  send() from client; */
        if (send(sock, s, echolen, 0) != echolen) 
        {
            Die("Mismatch in number of sent bytes");
        }
        if(strcmp(s,"exit") == 0) // check if exit is typed
        exit(0);
        fprintf(stdout, "Message from server: ");
        while (received < echolen) 
        {
            int bytes = 0;
            /* recv() from server; */
            if ((bytes = recv(sock, buffer, echolen, 0)) < 1) 
            {
                Die("Failed to receive bytes from server");
            }
            received += bytes;
            buffer[bytes] = '\0';
            /* Assure null terminated string */
            fprintf(stdout, buffer);
        }
        int bytes = 0;
// this d {...} while block will receive the buffer sent by server
        do {
            buffer[bytes] = '\0';
            printf("%s\n", buffer);
        } while((bytes = recv(sock, buffer, BUFFSIZE-1, 0))>=BUFFSIZE-1);
        buffer[bytes] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
        printf("\n");
    }
    }
```

There isn't any need to loop the client because the server exits after sending back the result.

Comment: While server sent `path` to client, it couldn't send `buffer` ( That have been sent from client ). Why?

Comment: It sends it on mine. Did you test this code as written? Or maybe I am not understanding what you mean?

Comment: In your original code the buffer isn't sent because both server and client are waiting on `recvfrom()`. I removed the extra while loop that receive data so server can send buffer. Please copy the whole code from here. Use strace whenever you are debugging.

Comment: Your code worked with me. Why do you use `signal`?. Addition, My old code use `while(1)` in client to repeat type request command until I type `"exit"`; However, when i add `while(1)` in client as previous that doesn't work. How to client request server  consecutive work without exit at the same time?.

Comment: The server code you originally wrote exit after a command. The client won't be able to send another request if the server is down. You will need to loop in the server code as well instead of exiting. I'll update my reply for the explanation of the codes I added and deleted.

Comment: @Lợi - I added while loops in both client and server.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a segmentation fault on this line because you're attempting to pass an integer to `strlen`:

```
write(STDOUT_FILENO,pipefd[1],strlen(pipefd[1]));
```

Your compiler should emit at least a warning for this; gcc does:

```
server.c:84: warning: passing argument 1 of 'strlen' makes pointer from integer without a cast
/usr/include/string.h:399: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'int'
```

If the intention was to write the value of `pipefd[1]` to `STDOUT_FILENO` as a binary integer then did you mean to do this?

```
write(STDOUT_FILENO,&pipefd[1],sizeof(pipefd[1]));
```

Comment: Can you explain what the parent/child piping is supposed to do? What is supposed to be sent by the parent. What is the child supposed to do with it and what is the child supposed to send back?

Comment: **the parent/child piping is supposed to do.**
The parent process will send the result execute of `execvp("ls",&address)` which is  a string of current directory such as a.txt b.pdf ... displayed on screen of server. I use `dup2(1,pipefd[1])` to put data from screen into pipefd[1]. The child process will receive data from parent process by pipefd[0] and send data to path variable. Finally, The data of path will be sent to client using  `send(sock,path,strlen(path),0)`